# Send parameter to ajax start function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax request as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "calculate.php",
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
    }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

Before the ajax starts, I want to send a parameter to function `ajaxStart` like below

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (xxx) {
  alert("parameter equals to="+xxx);
});
```

How can I send parameter `xxx` to `ajaxStart` when my request is started?
Is it possible to send parameter to `ajaxStart`?

Comment: It's not clear what you want this to do. Could you perhaps create a better example? Where is `xxx` supposed to come from?

Comment: It is possible send parameter to ajaxstart?

Comment: Not according to the documentation. https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/. You'd have to use a global variable or something

Answer (score 3):

You could use `$.ajaxSetup` or `$.ajaxSend` to change the data sent in the request before the request happens. Something like

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function( event, jqxhr, settings ) {
    settings.data = settings.data + '&param=value'
});
```

A more extendable approach would be to use `$.param` and check that there is data before extending it

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function( event, jqxhr, settings ) {
  var params = {param : 'test'};
  var sep    = settings.data && settings.data.length ? '&' : '';

  settings.data = settings.data + sep + $.param(params);
});
```